# Set separate variable values for production, development, release

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, redux

I am trying to figure out a way to set up different api endpoints based on application being in development, staging or production.

I've seen many developers use something line `process.env.NODE_ENV` but I tried that and I get an error saying

> property env is undefined

Tried this inside my component and action, but no luck. I don't fully understand why this can be used in some places but not others. And would like to know if there are any alternative solutions to the problem?

Comment: One way is to set a different configuration file per branch (if you use git). 
Another way is to pass an environment variable and make a request based on that variable such as if (env == 'production') end_points = require('.prod_api');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environmental variables are very useful to specify sensitive config options or to even remove unused code for libraries (e.g. React)

You'll need to specify your first environment variable first.

If you use Mac OS or linux then you can simply run

```
FOO=bar npm run start
```

That way you defined `process.env.FOO` and also created `process.env` variable.

If you use environmental variables more extensively, you can benefit from [better npm rum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run). In package.json you can define environmental variables cross-platform as such:

```
"start-prod": {
  "command": "node ./bin/server.js",
  "env": {
    "NODE_PATH": "./src",
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "PORT": 8080
  }
},
"start-dev": {
  "command": "node ./bin/server.js",
  "env": {
    "NODE_PATH": "./src",
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
    "PORT": 3000
  }
},
```

You can use this to your liking, but i certainly recommend setting NODE_ENV to true for production builds. Node modules will recognize that variable and will strip out development code. Your production build will become smaller as result of this simple step.

Other usages may include using environmental variables to:

- define API keys
- define availability of dev tools such as Redux Devtools
- specific build settings (e.g. enable DLL build in WebPack)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

- First in terminal set **`$export NODE_ENV=dev`**
- To check whether properly set **`$printenv NODE_ENV`** in terminal
- Then in node you can access like **`$console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`**
- So whenever my app wants environment variables at startup i do like this

  **$NODE_ENV=dev SQL_IP=127.0.0.1 node server.js**
- **Note** : Environmental variables when directly set through terminal they wipe out on closing terminal , so please set these variables in **`.bashrc`** file in your machine permanently